# Take all sites in a multisite environment offline at the same time

Tags: multi-sites, maintenance-mode

Is there an easy way to take all sites in a multisite environment offline at the same time, in just one step?  I really don't want to log in to each one and do it one at a time when I do something that involves all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) working, and have proper site aliases set up, the following should work:

```
drush @sites vset maintenance_mode 1
```

Turn take them all out, do

```
drush @sites vset maintenance_mode 0
```

If you are on Drupal 6, use `site_offline` instead of `maintenance_mode`.

Comment: I'm gonna set this up when I get a chance. Any good links for aliases?

Comment: I did a quick search when I answered, but didn't see anything in the docs.  You can copy drush/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php to drush/aliases.drushrc.php and edit.  The file is documented.  Looking at on of my multisite servers, fully defined aliases may not be needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you have drush installed you could use this snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
sites[0] = "http://www1.example.com";
sites[1] = "http://www2.example.com";
sites[2] = "http://www3.example.com";

for site in $sites; do
  drush vset --always-set --uri=$site site_offline 1 
done
```

I'm not an expert in sh scripting but something like that should work.